# Remove fading from unpopular answers on meta

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, meta

I believe answers that have received an aggregated score of -8 or less *should not* be faded out like it does on the main site.

Fading out poor answers on the main site serves as a visual cue for future readers to "be wary" of said answer because it is incorrect, is deprecated or is otherwise problematic and would yield unwanted results in an application.

However, meta is a place to discuss and exchange ideas. While answers can be still be negatively perceived, I don't really see the purpose of fading them. What visual cue or "warning" does that serve on meta? Answers are already sorted by score by default pushing the poor ones to the bottom.

Here's one example for consideration: Imagine an answer to a question that is very controversial, receiving 20 up-votes and 28 down-votes, giving it a score of -8 and fading it out. The majority might disagree with the answer, but being controversial I would still consider it a worthy read.

**TL;DR** I can see the benefits of fading poorly received answers on the main site, but why on meta?

Comment: Yeah fully agree that it needs to go, just like the upvote and downvote tooltips should be tailored to meta and posts with score -5 and below should not disappear from the front page (not really much of an issue, just make it a habit to look at the questions view instead). But I have the idea that meta-specific customisations are not trivial and thus worth the time.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't think this is a duplicate. The linked question proposes three options, one of which was chosen. This question asks to implement one of the options that wasn't chosen.

Comment: @Stijn: Then isn't the answer to this one _"Nope, we've chosen to do something else, it's already different than on main"_?

Comment: @Cerbrus, perhaps. But that post was posted over 3,5 years ago. Perhaps it's worth reconsidering the options? It's great that the threshold was lowered from -3 to -8, but *my* question is: *Why have it in the first place?*

Comment: I've added another dupe target about the same subject.